# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'aaa.zzz.yyy.xxx' (13)

Tags: mysql, centos, selinux

How to allow connection to the other MySQL server while se linux is enabled (`setenforce 1`)?

I received

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'aaa.zzz.yyy.xxx' (13)

When I enabled SE linux, but its working well when I disable it (`setenforce 0`)

Thank you,
AnD

Comment: Possible duplicate/wrong section http://serverfault.com/questions/240015/how-do-i-allow-mysql-connections-through-selinux

Comment: Thanks Nadir, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original answer is at: https://serverfault.com/questions/240015/how-do-i-allow-mysql-connections-through-selinux

To check SELinux

```
sestatus
```

To see what flags are set on httpd processes

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

To allow Apache to connect to remote database through SELinux

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Use -P option makes the change permanent. Without this option, the boolean would be reset to 0 at reboot.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```